# get self as invoking class in parent in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, constants, self

My first class which has constant. I want to make it to work somehow as dynamic value.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  TEST = ["#{self.name}", "test1"]
end


class FakePost < Post
end
```

In `rails console` I am trying to access TEST constant with `FakePost` but it is still show `self` as "Post" object. Is there any way to achieve this?

**Current:**

> irb(main):004:0> FakePost::Test
>
> => ["Post", "test1"]

But I want to return this result when I access Constant through Post not vi FakePost.

**Expected:**

> irb(main):004:0> FakePost::Test
>
> => ["FakePost", "test1"]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the code `TEST = ["#{self.name}", "test1"]` is only interpreted once, when the `Post` class is instantiated. After that it will be fixed as `["Post", "test1"]`.

Off the top of my head I can't think of a way of making this work with a constant, but if you were to replace it with a class method it works fine:

```
class Post
  def self.TEST
    [self.name, "test1"]
  end
end

class FakePost < Post
end

Post.TEST
#=> ["Post", "test1"]

FakePost.TEST
#=> ["FakePost", "test1"]
```

The reason this works is that the code inside the class method is interpreted at run time (i.e. when you call the method), rather than when the class is interpreted.  The timeline for both cases is as follows:

With `TEST` Constant:

1. Post class is instantiated and interpreted line by line.
2. `self.name` is interpreted and returns `'Post'`, as `self` is currently the `Post` class.
3. `Post::TEST` is set irrevocably to `["Post", "test1"]`
4. `FakePost` class is instantiated and inherits from `Post`, including the already-instantiated `TEST` constant of `["Post", "test1"]`
5. `FakePost::TEST == Post::TEST == ["Post", "test1"] #=> true`

With `TEST` class method:

1. Post class is instantiated and interpreted line by line.
2. Post class method `TEST` is added (but not interpreted yet).
3. `FakePost` class is instantiated and inherits `TEST` class method from `Post`. Still hasn't been interpreted yet.
4. When you run `Post.TEST` or `FakePost.TEST` the method will finally be interpreted. `self` will now be either `Post` or `FakePost` depending on which class called the `TEST` method.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I already know this answer but there are lots of places and checks required if I will made any change, thus I put question here. I want a solution to work.

Comment: @user4510998 as far as I know it is not possible the way you want to do it – see the timeline in my edit for the reason that this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, is best practice to create method to create with upcase ?

Comment: Good point, no it's not! I just wanted to show the similarity. Normally downcase is preferred for class methods.

Answer (score 1):

Constants can not be modified, so when you refer to it in the successor, it returns the value already assigned. Use class methods.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.test
    ["#{self.name}", "test1"] 
  end
end

class FakePost < Post
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out by others, `TEST` is set equal to `["Post", "test1"]` when `Post` is parsed; it is no different than the line having been simply `TEST = ["Post", "test1"]`.

To obtain the desired result from a constant (`TEST`), one possibility is to set `TEST` equal to a proc and then call that proc with `self` as an argument. This could be done as follows.

```
class News
  TEST = ->(slf) { ["#{slf}", "test1"] }
end

class FakeNews < News
end

News.instance_eval { self::TEST[self] }
  #=> ["News", "test1"]
FakeNews.instance_eval { self::TEST[self] }
  #=> ["FakeNews", "test1"]
```

[BasicObject#instance_eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) is needed to make `self` equal to `instance_eval`'s receiver. [Proc#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D) is the same as [Proc#call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Proc.html#method-i-call) (as well as `Proc.yield`, `Proc#===` and the depreciated `Proc#()` [written `TEST.(self)`]). Take your pick!